# Copy LaTex equations from Mathematica to Word directly?

Tags: mathematica

Is it possible to use command copy as latex equations directly from mathematica file and paste in Word equation editor 2007/2010. Not to save like .pdf or .jpg!

Alternative for web2tex or just this?

Regards!

Comment: Please consider supporting the mathematica proposal http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15787/mathematica

Unfortunately, I cannot help you with your question because I don't know anything about Word equation editor.

Comment: You'll want to look into `TeXForm[]` (in conjunction with `HoldForm[]`)...

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want, but if you can get TeX and want to use it in word, MathType could be a solution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathType This software can be installed to replace the equation editor in MS Word. \\However, I believe it's much better to use TeX for writing mathematics. (I supervised thesis where student decided to use MS Word and he had lot of problems.)\\ After a little googling I found out that Aurora might be a similar solution: http://elevatorlady.ca/

Comment: This comparison might be useful for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor - in the "Notes" column you can find out which of them work with MS Office.

Comment: There are several votes to close as off-topic. Until alternative SE proposals like those mentioned by @Phira come to being, I think this question is technically (by our FAQ) on topic as a question about the use of mathematical software. Though this is a situation where I think the OP would be much better off asking at the actual support website/forum for the software (this case Mathematica), than here, where the focus is much more on mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For copy/pasting mathematics between MS Word and Mathematica, the preferred format is [MathML](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/XML/tutorial/MathML.html). Since version 6 (as stated [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/07/31/going-wordless-at-the-advanced-mathematica-summer-school/)), this is [meant to be automatic](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin7/content/OptimizedNotebookErgonomics/CopypasteSupportWithMicrosoftWord2007EquationEditor.html). Unfortunately, as I don't have MS Office, I can't test this.

Wolfram Research also provides a [web service for converting expressions to and from MathML](http://www.mathmlcentral.com/).

Answer (score 2):

A solution is posted on the wolfram [website](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5698/) To quote:

> A brief example is given to demonstrate how to convert a Mathematica
>   notebook to a Microsoft Word document retaining the figures and
>   equations from the notebook. The conversions uses the freeware
>   application latex2rtf. The equations are converted to clickable fields
>   which open in the Word Equation Editor window.

Basically you save your notebook as tex, open an editor, and change all `equation` to `eqnarray` and then run `latex2rtf <filename>.tex`

A second solution, although not free one, is to use math type. It uses tex like syntax, so copy an equation (right click-> copy as latex) and paste it in the math type equation editor for word.

Comment: I downloaded the latex2rtf program, saved the equation as text. Now, what do you mean change all equation to eqnarray and then run latex2rtf?

Answer (score 2):

Another cludgy approach I have used with tolerable success is to render the expression as a graphic and then to cut and paste it as a Windows Metafile.  Yes, I know, it's horrible, but it isn't as horrible as turning the expression into a bitmap - the Metafile ought to retain vector and font information so it will render tidily at different resolutions.

Something like

Graphics[Text[]]

will pop your expression into the output cell, from which you can use the menu option to copy as a metafile

Steve

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using http://formulasheet.com. The site has a built-in equation editor which includes a 'Copy to Word' button. Also, if you sign up, you can upload a .tex file containing LaTeX formulas and it will extract a list of formulas, from which you can press the 'Copy to Word' button and avoid ever using MS Word's equation editor. The 'Copy to Word' functionality is provided by using MathML, as mentioned above.